# How to delete non-alphabetic characters while maintaining spaces between words?

Tags: java, string

I want to replace all non-alphabetic characters while maintaining a space between words:

```
String words = "game, rock, 456, pop, %";
```

The result should be:

```
String processedWords = "game rock pop";
```

I tried to run this code:

```
String processedWords = words.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "").replace(",",""));
```

but it gives me the result without blank spaces.

Comment: add `\s` into your regex `[^A-Za-z0-9\s]` -

Comment: Put a space in your character group.

Comment: In addition to this, if you do not want spaces at the front or back of the resulting string, you will have to call trim() on the resultant String.

Comment: Try this 
processedWords = words.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z\\s]", "").trim();

Comment: You could reword this as "I want to delete non-alphabetic characters except space", whereupon the answer becomes obvious. You might then want to reduce multiple spaces to single spaces -- there are already answers in SO about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep a space after 9

```
String processedWords = words.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", "");
```

Comment: `.replace(",","")` is redundant. There certainly won't be any commas in the result from the `replaceAll`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String processedWords = words.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9\\s]", "");
```

Comment: How to adopt this solution to reducing multiple spaces to single spaces?

Comment: OP said "a space" not "whitespace". So you should use a literal space char not `\s` - and probably discuss reducing multiple spaces to one.

Comment: @slim: If I write "[^A-Za-z0-9\s]", then I get `Illegal escape character in string lateral`.

Comment: @Dinosaurius `"[^A-Za-z0-9 ]"` -- because you shouldn't match tab, newline etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pattern macthed to filter charcters and then replace "," with space:-

```
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("game, rock, 456, pop, %");
        List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (m.find()) {
            resultList.add(m.group());
        }
        System.out.println(StringUtils.join(resultList , " "));
```

Comment: This is an excessively elaborate solution - but even if you do this, why not `StringUtils.join(resultList , " ")` without the `replaceAll`?